# How can I stop a user from entering 0-1 and characters that aren't a-z, along with catching pastes? (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to `preventDefault()` if a user presses a key that doesn't match `/[2-7a-z]/i`, and if they paste something containing that, it's prevented & a function is fired.

This is what I have so far.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    inp: ''
  },
  methods: {
    keyPressed: function(event) {
        var char = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        if (!/[2-7a-z]/i.test(char)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-on:keypress="keyPressed" v-model="inp">
</div>
```

How can I do the latter? (Preferably without external libraries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.preventDefault()` on `onpaste` will do. Which can be written in Vue's shorthand syntax as `@paste.prevent`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    inp: ''
  },
  methods: {
    onKeyDown: function(e) {
        var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (!/[2-7a-z]/i.test(char)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text"
         @keydown="onKeyDown"
         @paste.prevent
         v-model="inp">
</div>
```

However, I strongly advise you ***not to do it***. Data shows methods of restricting user's freedom to use form controls is a losing strategy. You lose users and, therefore, money. That is not to say you shouldn't validate their input or should trust it.

Or that you shouldn't tell them why their input is invalid. But don't restrict their freedom. Let them type anything and kindly inform them when the value they typed is unacceptable for your form.

Also note the above method is bypassable by simply opening the console, targeting the element and overwriting the `onpaste` function of the element. And nowadays you even have tools to do it for you, so, with the right browser extension I wouldn't even need to open the console.

Not to mention I could set the value of the `<input>` in about 10 different ways, without going through the `onpaste` event at all.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @throwaway000, you're welcome. Please note I've updated the answer with some advice.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm very grateful for your advice and I'll redo my form to just show an error if they try to submit it. Cheers!